# IE11 stopped working just I open devtools

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

IE11 stopped working just I open devtools.
http://prntscr.com/i8o70j

I use webpack, babel, es6, react

I dont't have any idea how to fix it!

Comment: Actually You are using the browser which is not yet supported for js bundled packages. For better experience use chrome, mozilla

Comment: It stopped working because the same styles include two times

Answer (score 0):

It stopped working because the same styles include two times